# pass variable value from inside the loop to outside

Tags: java, jsp, loops

I have a **for** loop and is changing the value of a variable previously declared outside the loop. What I have to do is to show that new value in an overlaid **div** that is being toggled on and off for a few seconds. Is any way to pass that value from inside the loop to the overlay outside the loop?

```
<script>
function toggle(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
</script>

<% 
int var=3; 

out.println("<div id='overlay'>");
out.println(var);
out.println("</div>");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
   var++;
   out.println("<script>");
   out.println("toggle('overlay');");
   out.println("</script>");
   Thread.sleep(3000); out.flush();
   out.println("<script>");
   out.println("toggle('overlay');");
   out.println("</script>");
   Thread.sleep(3000); out.flush();
}
%>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do...? because that said, some good suggestions might come up not to make it complex like this...

Comment: A sleep in the middle of writing to the client?!?! Scriptlets?

Comment: But we already now that var will be 6 :)

Comment: You need to to this all in JavaScript; it makes zero sense to pretend it's reasonable to do any of it in Java. Time to upgrade your client side skills.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically change the content of the div tag via javascript. For this you could probably output

```
out.println("<script>document.getElementById(\"overlay\").innerHTML = \"" + var + "\"</script>
```

That being said .. the whole setup looks a bit weird. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, what I really need are synchronous timers to timeup some events (which js doesn't have) and to show a modal box with a few values that I previously get them from db and are being altered inside the for loop. Maybe is not a brilliant example, but that's what the application is doing: running a piece of code, showing a modal box with the new altered values, then run another piece of code and do the same thing.. and so on

Comment: in php I was passing those values by reference and was easy, but java only knows to pass by value and doesn't seems to work. I was thinking to put all values on a session, but wanted to see if there is another way

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp? So timing in javascript is perfectly doable. Other than that, I think you are mixing up two things. Part of your code is run on the server. When you call out.println() you send data to the client. If you further want to edit the resulting webpage on the client, you have to do this with javascipt.

Comment: yes I did read and tried quite a lot to make all the timers synchronous, but are too many timers and it fails badly at one point. I know is messed up, but I need the code to run on the server, but I also have to change DOM elements according to changes. Thank you for your time and for the answer (+1 at least I can do)

Comment: @user2035693 You can call methods when timers expire, that's synchronous. It doesn't get much more synchronous than that.